# Subtract hours from SQL Server 2012 query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I am running queries on an alarm system signal automation platform database in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, and I am running into some hiccups.

My queries run just fine, but I am unable to refine my results to the level that I would like.

I am selecting some columns that are formatted as `DATETIME`, and I simply want to take the value in the column and subtract 4 hours from it (i.e., from GMT to EST) and then output *that* value into the query results.

All of the documentation I can find regarding `DATESUB()` or similar commands are showing examples with a specific `DATETIME` in the syntax, and I don't have anything specific, just 138,000 rows with columns I want to adjust time zones for.

Am I missing something big or will I just need to continue to adjust manually after I being manipulating my query result? Also, in case it makes a difference, I have a read-only access level, and am not interested in altering table data in any way.

Comment: Did you try dateadd?

Comment: DATEADD() can also "add" a negative value, but it is still looking for the start date at the end of the syntax. My "start date" to subtract from is already part of the query results. It's _that_ date that I want to adjust -4 hours.

Comment: DATEADD (datepart , number , date )

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, for starters, you need to know that you aren't restricted to use functions only on static values, you can use them on columns.

It seems that what you want is simply:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,-4,YourColumnWithDateTimes)
FROM dbo.YourTable
```

Comment: So would I use the DATEADD() in the place that I normally would have
`SELECT` 
   `eventname as 'Event',`
    `DATEADD(HOUR,-4,eventtime) as 'Time'`
`FROM dbo.events`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the assistance. I just ran this and it worked perfectly. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe it will be helpful

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE());
```

[DATEPART docs from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420(loband).aspx)

Comment: It looks like I found an answer to my question already, but I will use the link to get more familiar. Thanks!