# Function to return date of 4hrs minus from given date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Emp`:

```
Create table Emp
(
     empno int, 
     ename varchar(50), 
     doj varchar(30), 
     salary int
);

insert into Emp 
values (1, 'raj', '2010-06-30 08:10:45', 5000),
       (2, 'kiran', '2018-12-05 18:20:24', 40000),
       (3, 'akbar', '2015-04-12 20:02:45', 9000),
       (4, 'nitin', '2010-03-11 02:10:23', 3000),
       (5, 'Rahul', '2013-12-03 13:23:30', 15000);
```

**Emp** table:

```
-------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------------
empno            ename              doj                      salary
-------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------------
1             raj                2010-06-30 08:10:45         5000
2             kiran              2018-12-05 18:20:24        40000
3             akbar              2015-04-12 20:02:45         9000
4             nitin              2010-03-11 02:10:23         3000
5             Rahul              2013-12-03 13:23:30        15000
-------+------------------+-------------------------+-----------------
```

Here I want to subtract 4hrs from `doj` and should return the doj values.

I wrote this SQL query and it's working:

```
select 
    format(cast(doj as datetime) - cast('04:00' as datetime), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss') "4Hrs_Minus" 
from emp;
```

Now I want to use a function which should return the o/p as above...

Query output:

```
    -------+-----------------------+---------------------
    empno             doj             4Hrs_Minus        
    -------+-----------------------+---------------------
    1         2010-06-30 08:10:45     2010-06-30 04:10:45   
    2         2018-12-05 18:20:24     2018-12-05 14:20:24
    3         2015-04-12 20:02:45     2015-04-12 16:02:45
    4         2010-03-11 02:10:23     2010-03-11 22:10:23
    5         2013-12-03 13:23:30     2013-12-03 09:23:30
    -------+-----------------------+----------------------
```

Comment: DATEADD(hh,-4,@d)

Comment: using function it should return values..r
CREATE FUNCTION  emp (@doj varcha)  
RETURNS TABLE  
AS  
RETURN   
select 
    format(cast(doj as datetime) - cast('04:00' as datetime), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss') "4Hrs_Minus" 
from emp;
end

am beginner in sqlserver, not sure in writing functions.

Comment: why do you need a function if there is a simple command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract hours from SQL Server 2012 query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32895736/subtract-hours-from-sql-server-2012-query-result)

Comment: i need to use this function block inside packages...so i want to create function.

Comment: But.. the function **already exists**, and it's name is `DATEADD()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT empno, doj, DATEADD(hh, -4, doj) as [4hrs_Minus] FROM Emp
```

Documentation:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017